# Add viewcontroller to navigation controller programmatically then push another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to append couple of viewcontrollers in array of viewcontroller of a navigation controller, then want push third viewcontroller of the same navigation controller.
My code is as follows

```
let navigationController = getCurrentNavController()

let listVC = UIStoryboard.loadListViewController()
navigationController.viewControllers.append(listVC)
                
let detailVC = UIStoryboard.loadDetailsViewController()
navigationController.viewControllers.append(detailVC)
                
let thirdVC = UIStoryboard.loadThird()
navigationController.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
```

The thirdVC is push on the navigation controller,
the problem is when i pop thirdVC,
I don't find detailVC or listVC.
Is this possible?
if yes please help.

Answer (score 3):

Don't edit the `viewControllers` array directly. That is why the `animated` parameter exists.

A solution may be to add the viewControllers in between after 0.25 seconds (the duration of the push animation) by doing:

```
let navigationController = getCurrentNavController()
var viewControllers = navigationController.viewControllers

let listVC = UIStoryboard.loadListViewController()
viewControllers.append(listVC)
                
let detailVC = UIStoryboard.loadDetailsViewController()
viewControllers.append(detailVC)
                
let thirdVC = UIStoryboard.loadThird()
viewControllers.append(thirdVC)
navigationController.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(now() + 0.25) {
    navigationController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Worked ;-) Thanks, 
One doubt is why do i need to push *thirdVC* 
If i am appending it in viewControllers array

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you do not want to modify the navigation controller's `viewControllers` directly.

But, you also don't need to do any explicit "pushing":

```
    let navigationController = getCurrentNavController()

    let listVC = UIStoryboard.loadListViewController()
    let detailVC = UIStoryboard.loadDetailsViewController()
    let thirdVC = UIStoryboard.loadThird()

    var vcs = navigationController.viewControllers

    vcs.append(listVC)
    vcs.append(detailVC)
    vcs.append(thirdVC)

    navigationController.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
```

This will animate `thirdVC` in from the current view controller, just as if you had pushed it, but it will also insert `listVC` and `detailVC` into the navigation controller's stack so the "Back" button will take you through `detailVC` and `listVC`.